# Footnote spacing difference between Word and PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

This is a really bizarre thing.... The footnote spacing in final PDF file is different from the spacing defined in the Word. Why???

[image]

I have search a lot but didn't find anything useful. Microsoft Word version is 2013 and I print the the document to PDF using Foxit printer and the PDF compatibility is set to 1.5. The problem is not related to A4 and Letter page sizes (a very common mistake when converting a word document to PDF).

The second strange thing is that the footnote numbers in the Word are in English, but the numbers in PDF are in non-English (Unicode). Since the text is non-english, the number above each word (in the main text) are in unicode also

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Why not saving with Word's 'Save As...' function and setting the file type as PDF? It didn't cause this trouble to me when I did this.

Comment: Because I want to convert some pages. "save as" will convert all of the pages which is not what I  want

Comment: I posted an answer. Comment on it if it doesn't work since your problem might be caused from the engine that saves your document as PDF so I'm not certain.

Comment: I edited to add another answer in case the problem went with OP's PDF engine.

Comment: Will you please post a sample .docx and pdf that demonstrate your issue? I'll delete the answer so we'll continue here

Comment: I think the problem is the non-english text. Let me see how I can reproduce that in a simple way... because the document is big.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction in Word, it will correct the language changing problem:

view --> draft, then go to: references --> show notes --> at the bottom of the page the footnotes will appear, select all of them --> choose the English font from the font tab (mostly "Times New Roman") --> save

Answer (score 0):

For the first question. follow this instruction.
Open The Pdf file with Adobe Reader.
Then click Edit> Edit Text & Images in menubar.
AND drag each digit and drop it in its proper place OR select digit(s) and use (up down left right) keys to put it in the proper place.
 Drag and drop each digit. it's simply

My Adobe Reader version is 2015 DC.